# How to use special characters in hive table and schema names?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am on hive 1.2. Is it possible to use special characters in hive table and schema names ? I am using back quotes (`) in column name to have keywords and special characters. I want to create table something like this

```
create table `!#$`(`column`int, `string` string);
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [!#$]: is not a valid table name
```

Note: It allows me to use special character in column names but not as a table or schema name.

Please let me know if it is possible.

Thank you for the help!